# Using the Vue "v-slot" feature for a named slot in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I come here because I can't find how to use "**v-slot**" when using the syntax leveraging a javascript object. This syntax I am talking about is the one presented in the course course **[Intro to Vue3](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-3/intro-to-vue3)** I followed *(If this syntax has a particular name, apologize for my explanation: I would be happy to know it)*.
Below screenshot shows an example:

[image: Syntax handling javascript object]

I have a first file named **ComponentToBeCalled.js**, containing the following code for building a vue component:

```js
app.component('component-to-be-called', {
            data: function(){},
            props: {},
              template:
              /*html*/
              `<div>
                   SOME_HTML_HERE
               </div>`,
              computed: {},
              methods: {}
            })
```

I have a second file named **ParentComponent.js** with the following code for building another vue component:

```js
app.component('parent-component', {
    data: function(){},
    props: {},
      template:
      /*html*/
      `<div>
           <slot name="SLOT_NAME"></slot>
       </div>`,
      computed: {},
      methods: {}
    })
```

--> My objective would be to build 'component-to-be-called' within 'parent-component'.
From what I read, the classic syntax for defining a named slot in a CompenentToBeCalled.vue file would be:

```html
<component-to-be-called>
  <template v-slot:SLOT_NAME>
    <div>
         SOME_HTML_HERE
    </div>
  </template>
</component-to-be-called>
```

**Do you know what is the equivalent when we play with a javascript object ?**

__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first bit of code is defining a regular component (`component-to-be-called`). Your second bit of code is defining a component which has a slot (`parent-component`).

If you want to have a `component-to-be-called` inside a `parent-component` using the slot, you would do as follows:

```
<parent-component>
    <template v-slot:SLOT_NAME>
        <component-to-be-called />
    </template>
</parent-component>
```

This would render as:

```
<div>   //This is from parent-component
    <div>   //This is from component-to-be-called
        SOME_HTML_HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

The official [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) has some nice diagrams to help you get your head around what goes where. Be careful though that what the docs calls `parent template` is the template that's using the Component with the defined slot.

This should all work the same with plain javascript syntax (`template: "<div>...`) or Single File Components.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and help Titz, 

It seems that I misunderstood the 'v-slot' feature. The parent gives some content in the child that has the slot and I was looking for the opposite: ie leveraging a child template to contexualize the content of a parent (and I wanted to avoid using 'v-if' as several possible children could be called by the parent).